# Have I fully installed java? Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, installation

I wanted to update Java on a remote machine. When I began, I ran the following query and got the following response:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

When I re-installed Java and ran the same query, I get:

```
$ java -version
bash: /c/windows/system32/java: No such file or directory
```

If I look at my Control Panel, I see:

- Java 8 Update 201 (64-bit)
- Java(TM) SE Development Kit 11.0.2 (64-bit)

Why don't I see the same response as I did originally? Do I just need to add the command paths to the system PATH variable? Also, have I installed the VM?

I've spent several hours trying to figure this out, and I keep getting stuck on other things I don't understand. For instance, I tried downloading the tarball, but I cannot for the life of me get the configure command to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

`setx -m JAVA_HOME "<JDK_DIRECTORY>"`

to set JAVA_HOME. change the `<JDK_DIRECTORY>`, to be the folder with the jdk on your machine

For example: If jdk is in program files:

`setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_XX"`

Comment: That did it! Thank you!!